# Why is the windows ISO file much smaller than the installed OS?

Tags: windows, iso-image

For example,

the windows 7 ISO file is around 3.5GB. Yet when installed its around 10GB.

Is this because of compression,

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is because of compression. The data on the DVD/ISO are stored in a large file called `install.wim`. This [WIM file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Imaging_Format) is using the [LZX compression algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LZX_%28algorithm%29#Windows_Imaging_Format_.28WIM.29_files) to make it smaller.